# Can not list database object results in Codeigniter view

Tags: database, codeigniter, view

I am trying to make an SQL query and make a loop in the view file in CodeIgniter. I keep getting the following error.

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: data</p>
<p>Filename: include_files/search_inc.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 14</p>
```

Here's my model:

```
class Search_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_locations()
    {
            $query = $this->db->query("Select bolgekodu,bolgeadi from bolgeler");
            return $query->result();
    }

}
```

Here's my Controller:

```
$this->load->model('Search_model');
$data['locations'] = $this->Search_model->get_locations();
$this->load->view('include_files/search_inc',$data);
```

And here's how I try to list it in the view:

```
 <?php
               foreach($data->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->bolgeadi;
    echo $row->bolgekodu;
}?>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you initialze `$data` as  `$data=[] or $data=array()` before accessing `$data['locations']`? I hope defining it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already taken and returned the result set from the query in model. So in view u can just use $locations inside the foreach to get the desired result.

```
foreach($locations as $row)
{
    echo $row->bolgeadi;
    echo $row->bolgekodu;
}
```